# Oracle impdb on windows generates a subdirectory

Tags: oracle-12c, impdp

I am importing to a windows oracle, a dump file produced on Linux. But oracle generates a subfolder in the `dpdump` directory /76E0F91BE49D480CB2633847BD640FC5\  and causes an "ORA-31640: unable to open dump file" error.

> ```
> ORA-39001: invalid argument value
> ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
> ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "E:\oracle\admin\orcl\dpdump\/76E0F91BE49D480CB2633847BD640FC5\backup_DB_01.dmp" for read
> ORA-27041: unable to open file
> OSD-04002: unable to open file
> O/S-Error: (OS 2) The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

I shut down oracle and deleted that long subfolder. But it gets recreated every time I run `impdp`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Ask your System admin to grant `read write permission` on the directory (where dump is located) and run cmd as admin and then try to run impdp command.

For more details : 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_31640_unable_to_open_dump_file_for_read.htm

Comment: This looks more like permission issue on the dmp files.
-a---- 10/3/2018 1:45 PM 96583438336 backup_DB_01.dmp